# Partial view within a partial view not posting

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm still relatively new to the whole MVC way of doing things, so bear with me on this.

I'm currently working on an existing MVC website, adding Admin features to it as needed.  There is one main Admin View.  All other CRUD operations are handled by Partial Views loaded into the one single Admin View.  To this point, I've had no issues adding all of these partial views.  Right now, there are two tables: Email_Queue and Smtp_Server.  The business rules state that you must have a Smtp_Server record before you can create an Email_Queue record.

Therefore, to make it nicer for the user, I have a option to create a Smtp_Server within the Create partial view for the Email_Queue.  I can get the Create partial view for the Smtp_Server to open in a modal pop-up...I can get all of its validation (set in the Model) to trigger...I can get the cancel button to close the modal popup.  However, I cannot seem to get the submit button on the Smtp_Server partial view to post.

The end goal for all of this is eventually get that to post, and then have a dropdown in the Email_Queue partial view update with the new Smtp_server I just added.  For now, I'd be happy with the Smtp_Server just saving what I type in.

So, here's some code.  First, the Email_Queue partial view (I've removed extra fields to keep it shorter):

```
@model Models.Email_QueueModel

<div class="main_column_leftfull">
<!--=========Graph Box=========-->
<div class="box expose">
    <!-- A box with class of expose will call expose plugin automatically -->
    <div class="header">
        Create E-Mail Queue
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function CancelAddSmtpServer() {
                var windowElement = $('#QueueCreate');
                windowElement.hide();
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {

            var windowElement = $('#QueueCreate');
            var undoButton = $('#opener-popup');
            undoButton
                .bind('click', function(e) {
                    windowElement.data('tWindow').open();
                    undoButton.hide();})
                .toggle(!windowElement.is(':visible'));
                    windowElement.bind('close', function() {
                    undoButton.show();

                });
            });

            function CloseWindow() {
                var windowElement = $('#QueueCreate').data('tWindow');
                windowElement.close();
            }

        </script>
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("_Create", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "subForm", HttpMethod = "Post" }))
        {
            <fieldset>
                @Form.HiddenID("DepartmentId")
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QueueName)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QueueName, new { @class = "textfield" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QueueName)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailServerConfig)
                    @Html.DropDownList("EmailServerConfig", "Select E-Mail Server Configuration...")
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailServerConfig)
                </div>

                <div id="opener-popup" class="editor-label" style="cursor:pointer;">
                    Add SMTP Server
                </div>

                <div id="popup_content" title="Popup Title" style="display:none;">
                    @Html.Partial("../Email_SmtpServer/_QueueCreate")
                </div>

                @(Html.Telerik().Window()
                    .Name("QueueCreate")
                    .Modal(true)
                    .Title("Add SMTP Server")
                    .Scrollable(false)
                    .Draggable(true)
                    .Resizable()
                    .Visible(false)
                    .Content
                    (
                        @<text>
                            @Html.Partial("../Email_SmtpServer/_QueueCreate", new DATEL.MM.Models.Email_SmtpServerModel())
                        </text>
                    )
                )

                <br />
                <p>
                    @Form.Submit(value: "Create E-Mail Queue")
                   <input id="btnCancelEmail_QueueCreate" type="button" value="Cancel" class="button" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        }
        <div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Next, the partial view I created for the modal popup:

```
@model Models.Email_SmtpServerModel

<div class="main_column_leftfull">
<!--=========Graph Box=========-->
<div class="box expose">
    <!-- A box with class of expose will call expose plugin automatically -->
    <div class="header">
        Create SMTP Server
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("_QueueCreate", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "subForm", HttpMethod = "Post" }))
        {
            <fieldset>
                @Form.HiddenID("SMTPServerId")
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ServerName)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ServerName, new { @class = "textfield" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ServerName)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ServerDesc)
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ServerDesc, new { @class = "textfield" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ServerDesc)
                </div>

                <br />
                <p>
                    @Form.Submit(value: "Create SMTP Server")

                    <input id="btnCancelEmail_SmtpServerQueueCreate" type="button" value="Cancel" class="button" onclick="CloseWindow();" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

And finally, here's my controller code for _QueueCreate:

```
[HttpPost]
    public virtual PartialViewResult _QueueCreate(Email_SmtpServerModel model, FormCollection fc)
    {
        ViewBag.HasError = "none";
        try
        {
            string errorMessage = "";
            BusinessLogic.Email_SmtpServer dbESS = new BusinessLogic.Email_SmtpServer(AppManager.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).ConnectionString);
            model.SMTPServerId = System.Guid.NewGuid();
            model.CreatedDateGMT = DateTime.Now;
            model.CreatedUserId = AppManager.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).UserId;

            if (dbESS.Insert(model, out errorMessage))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", errorMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.HasError = "none";
                return PartialView("../Email_Queue/_Create");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            ViewBag.HasError = "true";
            return PartialView("../Email_Queue/_Create");
        }
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

If I need to post more code, please let me know.

TL;DR version: Well, just look at the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you not force the submit button to submit on click

```
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit Form" onclick="this.form.submit()" />
```

Or really just use jQuery to look for the onclick and then post using ajax

```
$('input[name="btnSubmit"').click(function() {
//you will need to get form variables

$.ajax({
type:"POST",
data: { id = var1, parameter = var2 }
datatype: "json",
success: function (data){
//whatever needs done
},
error: function(){
alert("error");
}

});
```

MVC controller

```
public jsonresult somename(string id, string parameter)
{ 
return Json("SUCCESS");
}
```

or

```
public jsonresult somename(FormCollection fc)
{
strind id = fc["id"];
string parameter = fc["parameter"];
return Json("SUCCESS");
}
```

Comment: I actually did eventually use jQuery to get the partial view to post.  Everything saves, now I just need to close the modal popup and update the dropdown on success.